# How to set svn server in Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise svn software. Do I have to set svn server by commands ??? but where I have to give command to set username and password and there is also a problem to set URL?

Comment: first, do you want to install your svn server on linux or windows?

Comment: I want to install it on windows.

Comment: Why you **even don't try** to read SVN-Book? It will eliminate a lot of noob questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, I had to teach some non-technical students the basics about version control.

My option at that time was http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

It's incredibly easy to install and use SVN server implementation.

Comment: Can I connect it with Tortoise SVN?